# Plotly JS crossfilter on id with multiple graphs

Tags: javascript, plotly, crossfilter

I am trying to build a dashboard with multiple plotly graphs in Javascript. I would like to implement a crossfilter function within the charts where the selected data in a graph will be highlighted in the other graphs on the same id. Please see an example below:

Dataset Graph 1:

```
[{
    "id": "1",
    "ItemWidth" : 545,
    "ItemLength" : 234
},
{
    "id": "2",
    "ItemWidth" : 33,
    "ItemLength" : 2234234
}]
```

Dataset Graph 2:

```
[{
        "id": "1",
        "ItemSold" : 44,
        "AnotherAtt" : 567
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "ItemSold" : 1213,
        "AnotherAtt" : 656
    }]
```

As you can see the datasets are different but they have the same id. I would like to know how to implement a crossfilter on id based on the datasets within multiple graphs where they share the same id.

Any help and advise is appreciated.

Comment: Hi @UchihaZootje, welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately this question is out of scope here, because questions should be specific and you should have an example of what you have tried so far. I know that plotly’s Dash product does some of what you are looking for. I don’t know of any mature libraries that integrate plotly with the crossfilter library.